# Когда указана директория C:\, FindFirst работает. А если указывается путь подпапки, то нет

Tags: delphi, listview

Допустим, на форме имеем компоненты TImageList1 и ListView1. В первом компоненте загружаются картинки. Во втором компоненте они отображаются. Код следующий:

```
procedure TForm1.fillListView(path: string; mask: string = '*.jpg');
var
  sr:  TSearchRec;
  img: TPicture;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  pic: TBitMap;
  x,y: integer;
begin
  img := TPicture.Create;
  bmp := TBitMap.Create;
  pic := TBitMap.Create;

  With Form1 do
  if FindFirst(path +mask, faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if (sr.Name<>'.') and (sr.Name<>'..') and (sr.Attr<>faDirectory) then
      //if (sr.Attr and $20) = $20 then
      begin
        try
          img.LoadFromFile(path + sr.Name);
        except
          Continue;
        end;
        bmp.Assign(img.Graphic);
        x:=bmp.Width;
        y:=bmp.Height;
        pic.Width := ImageList1.Width;
        pic.Height:= ImageList1.Height;
        pic.Canvas.Brush.Color :=clWhite;
        pic.Canvas.FillRect(Canvas.ClipRect);
        pic.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0,0,pic.Width, Round((pic.Height*y)/x)), bmp);
        ImageList1.Add(pic, nil);

        with ListView1.Items.Add do
        begin
          Caption := sr.Name;
          ImageIndex := ListView1.Items.Count-1;
        end;
      end;
    until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
    FindClose(sr);
  end;
  img.Free;
  bmp.Free;
  pic.Free;
end;
```

Для вывода списка картинок используется код:

```
  Form1.ListView1.Clear;
  ImageList1.Clear;
  FillListView('C:\', '*.jpg');
  FillListView('C:\', '*.bmp');
```

Проблема в том, что ListView отображает картинки, только когда директория указана C:\ (корневая директория). Если указывается путь подпапки, то она не хочет работать. В чем может быть ошибка... Подскажите, буду признателен. Может с FindFirst что-то не так?

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался сам.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема со слешами. Проверьте чему равно `path+sr.name`, скорее всего слеша не хватает.

1)

```
if FindFirst(path +'\'+ mask, faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
```

2)

```
img.LoadFromFile(path + '\'+ sr.Name);
```

3)

```
FillListView('C:', '*.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter` из модуля `SysUtils`, она добавит необходимый разделитель пути в конце, если его нет:

```
if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path) + mask, faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
...
img.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path) + sr.Name);
```